# js code not getting executed in my rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, ruby-on-rails-4

In an autocomplete.js file in my assets folder I have:

```
  function initialize_autocomplete() {


    $("#mainPage").bind("pageshow", function(e) {
      console.log("test");

      var data = ['C', 'Clojure', 'Jenny!', 'Java', 'Scala', 'Objective-C', 'C++', 'PHP', 'C#', '(Visual) Basic', 'Python', 'Perl', 'JavaScript', 'Ruby', 'Visual Basic .NET', 'Transact-SQL', 'Lisp', 'Pascal', 'Bash', 'PL/SQL', 'Delphi/Object Pascal', 'Ada', 'MATLAB'];

      $("#searchField").autocomplete({
        target: $('#suggestions'),
        source: data,
        link: 'target.html?term=',
        minLength: 1,
        matchFromStart: false
      });
    });
    }
```

In my application.js I have:

```
//= require autocomplete
```

In my html.erb file I have:

```
<div data-role="page" id="mainPage">

    <div data-role="content">

      <p>
        In this example autoComplete uses a local array comprised of strings. This also shows an example of the matchFromStart property set to false.
      </p>


      <p>
        <input type="text" id="searchField" placeholder="Categories">
        <ul id="suggestions" data-role="listview" data-inset="true"></ul>
      </p>

    </div>

  </div>

  <script>
  $(function() {
  // this function can be found in autocomplete.js
  initialize_autocomplete();
  });
</script>
```

The content loads in my browser - I can see the input box etc, but the javascript is not executing. You will see I have

```
console.log("test");
```

but 'test' is not appearing in Console, in Chrome.When I run the code as a standalone project without putting it in my rails project, it works as intended - drop down appears, I see 'test' in Console. Any help would be welcome.

Changed my code to (as suggested by Omar, below):

```
<div data-role="page" id="mainPage">

    <h1>Welcome#auto_complete</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/welcome/auto_complete.html.erb</p>

        <div data-role="content">

            <p>
                In this example autoComplete uses a local array comprised of strings. This also shows an example of the matchFromStart property set to false.
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="text" id="searchField" placeholder="Categories">
                <ul id="suggestions" data-role="listview" data-inset="true"></ul>

            </p>
        </div>

                <script>
  // this function can be found in autocomplete.js
  initialize_autocomplete();
  console.log ("test");
</script>

    </div>
```

And my autocomplete.js:

```
  function initialize_autocomplete() {

$(document).on("pageshow", "mainPage", function {
      console.log("test");

      var data = ['C', 'Clojure', 'Jenny!', 'Java', 'Scala', 'Objective-C', 'C++', 'PHP', 'C#', '(Visual) Basic', 'Python', 'Perl', 'JavaScript', 'Ruby', 'Visual Basic .NET', 'Transact-SQL', 'Lisp', 'Pascal', 'Bash', 'PL/SQL', 'Delphi/Object Pascal', 'Ada', 'MATLAB'];

      $("#searchField").autocomplete({
        target: $('#suggestions'),
        source: data,
        link: 'target.html?term=',
        minLength: 1,
        matchFromStart: false
      });
    });
});
```

But I get the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: initialize_autocomplete is not defined
```

Comment: which jQM version are you using?

Comment: http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js

Comment: Ok, change `$("#mainPage").bind("pageshow", function(e) {` to this `$(document).on("pageshow", "mainPage", function {` and place all code inside #mainPage div. remove `$(function` as the code will be executed when page is shown.

Comment: @Omar Thanks for that. Did as you said but now I'm getting the error - Uncaught ReferenceError: initialize_autocomplete is not defined

Comment: check the code here http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/UQWFh/

Comment: ok, will do that now. While you were putting this up I was actually editing my question to show my new code...

Comment: not sure what your fiddle is supposed to do

Comment: instead of calling a function, place code inside `pageshow` and place all code inside page div. just copy/paste code in fiddle and try again.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to wrap code in `<script>`, I've updated the same fiddle.

Comment: @Omar Thanks for your help, but still not working, when I copy the code exactly. It works if I copy it in a html file and run it as is, but not in a html.erb file. not even being executed. It's some rails thing....

Comment: Well, it looks like rail issue, code should be placed somewhere rails can read/execute.

Answer (score 0):

$(function() { }); binds to "pageload" but then you are trying to bind an element to "pageshow". I recommend simplifying your events:

In autocomplete.js:

```
- function initialize_autocomplete() { }); // delete
- $("#mainPage").bind("pageshow", function(e) { }); //delete
```

Now you can do:

```
$(function() {
    console.log("test");
    // Put the rest of your code
});
```

In Rails there is no reason why you should tightly couple HTML with js code.